# VBA userform to execute selections only after hitting command button

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform, commandbutton

I am having a hard time to make vba to execute my selection only after pressing the command button (The GO button in this case). Attached are the picture of the userform, which is not made by activeX control, and the code I am working on. Thanks!

[image: Picture of Userform]

```
Private Sub MR_Click()

If MR.Value = True Then
Rows(6).Delete
End If

End Sub

Private Sub PMS_Click()

If PMS.Value = True Then
Rows(7).Delete
End If

End Sub

Private Sub VOIDMR_Click()

If VOIDMR.Value = True Then
Rows(13).Delete
End If

End Sub

Private Sub VOIDPMS_Click()

If VOIDPMS.Value = True Then
Rows(14).Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of doing your work into each checkboxes `_Click` event, use the `_Click`event of the button. And be aware that deleting one row will makes all rows below go up by one.

Comment: I see a typo here `Applicatioin.Undo`. Also I don't see the code associated with pushing the "GO" button. Are your checkboxes the ones with the Click events? Seems to be that this will be trigger when the option is selected not when GO is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @nbayly, I was trying to use the UNDO code, but it seems I can't undo thing after running Macro. That's why I would like the macro to hold on the action before hitting the GO button.

Comment: Hello, @VincentG, I am aware of that if the user keeps checking and unchecking the checkbox, bad thing will happen, that's why I would like the action only carries out after hitting the GO button.

Comment: You can check the status of each checkbox when you click Go. You don't have to add code on the click event for each checkbox. Just loop through all 4 checkboxes and check the status when you finally run the code. Undo first and then delete the rows you want.

Comment: Hi, @nbayly, since I am really new to using userform, what I am getting from you is to empty the code in those four private subs and put those code in the GO button, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, using a "Go" button's `_Click` event procedure (presumably `GO_Click()`, but modify if needed) to check against each of the checkboxes and do the deletion accordingly.

```
Private Sub GO_Click()
If MR.Value = True Then
    Rows(6).Delete
End If
If PMS.Value = True Then
    Rows(7).Delete
End If
If VOIDMR.Value = True Then
    Rows(13).Delete
End If
If VOIDPMS.Value = True Then
    Rows(14).Delete
End If
End Sub
'These event procedures won't do anything, and can be removed:
Private Sub MR_Click()
End Sub
Private Sub PMS_Click()
End Sub
Private Sub VOIDMR_Click()
End Sub
Private Sub VOIDPMS_Click()
End Sub
```

The checkboxes' `_Click` event procedures are no longer needed.

To note about the event procedures, they will fire whenever the event occurs. So for an checkbox with a `_Click` event, any time the user checks (or unchecks) `_Click` handler will execute.

As noted, exercise caution when deleting elements from a collection, as this typically needs to be done in reverse order (when you delete row 6, row 7 becomes row 6, so if both MR and PMS are checked, what's in Row 7 initially will not be deleted). This may require some additional code change, but very simply it seems by just re-ordering the commands within `GO_Click`, should handle this:

```
Private Sub GO_Click()
If VOIDPMS.Value = True Then
    Rows(14).Delete
End If
If VOIDMR.Value = True Then
    Rows(13).Delete
End If
If PMS.Value = True Then
    Rows(7).Delete
End If
If MR.Value = True Then
    Rows(6).Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, one quick follow-up question, can I have the go button to execute the above command and close itself at the same time?

Comment: You want it to close the userform? Yes, just add `Unload Me` before `End Sub`.

Comment: @YSCheung also see my updated code, deleting rows should *always* be done in reverse index order, otherwise undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

just a stylistic variation on @DavidZemens code:

```
Private Sub GO_Click()
    With Me '<-- reference the userform
        Select Case True
            Case .MR '<-- if MR checkbox control is True
                Rows(6).Delete
            Case .PMS '<-- if PMS checkbox control is True
                Rows(7).Delete
            Case .VOIDMR '<-- if VOIDMR checkbox control is True
                Rows(13).Delete
            Case .VOIDPMS '<-- if VOIPMS checkbox control is True
                Rows(14).Delete
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @YSCheung, Is the user supposed to check only one of the checkboxes?

Comment: This definitely will not work with multiple checkbox selections.

Comment: To enforce single-selection, checkboxes should not be used (favor Option Buttons for similar UI, or ListBox/ComboBox without allowing multi-select).

Comment: @DavidZemens, that's what I started mumbilng about so I asked the OP about

Comment: Users are allowed to check all the boxes if they need to... I am just starting noticing some issues also. Is there a way to workaround this? Thanks!

Comment: So what's your real need? Should user only be allowed to check only one checkbox "per userform session"?

Comment: @YSCheung, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi, I managed to get through it by reverse deleting the row with a much better user form. Deleting is not the best way to do it in my case but my coworker and i are happy with the result, thanks!